# How to multiply ethers.parseEther() with hardhat?

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

I have a price object that I'm trying to perform multiplication on

```
const PRICE_ONE = ethers.parseEther("0.05");
const test = PRICE_ONE * 2;
```

but I can't get the multiply to work when running `npx hardhat test`

it gives me the error

`TypeError: Cannot mix BigInt and other types, use explicit conversions`.

Tried searching for a `hardhat` example of how to multiply, but couldn't find any on google.

So I threw it into chatgpt and it tells me to do

`const test = PRICE_ONE.mul(2);`

but that gives the error

`TypeError: PRICE_ONE.mul is not a function`

How do I multiply `PRICE_ONE` with 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `parseEther()` function ([docs](https://docs.ethers.org/v6/api/utils/#parseEther)) returns JS native type `BigInt`. `BigInt` cannot be used together with another JS native type `Number` (which is the type of your literal `2` in the code).

The most straightforward solution is to multiply the `BigInt` returned from `parseEther()` with another `BigInt`.

You can declare a `BigInt` using a `n` suffix after the literal:

```
const PRICE_ONE = ethers.parseEther("0.05");

// `test` is now of type `BigInt`
const test = PRICE_ONE * 2n;
```

---

The `.mul()` function that GPT recommended you is used for example in BN.js library ([link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bn.js)) that Ethers used in previous versions (up to v5) instead of the native `BigInt` (introduced in Ethers v6).

Comment: Excellent answer. Thank you!